# inArray() does not work for first item of a loop

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have some code like this, well here is the part that is most important and does not work as I want.

```
<div class="somediv" data-dummy="class11">some text</div>
<div class="somediv" data-dummy="class12">some flying saucers</div>
<div class="somediv" data-dummy="class13">some crazy jpg</div>


var AllFirstCssClasses = [ 'class11', 'class12', 'class13' ];
var AllSecondCssClasses = [ 'class21', 'class22', 'class23' ];

for (var index = 0; index < $('div.somediv').length; index++){
   var firstCssClass = $('div.somediv').eq(index).attr('data-dummy');
   var index2 = $.inArray(firstCssClass, AllFirstCssClasses);
   $('div.somediv').eq(index).addClass(firstCssClass + ' ' +  AllSecondCssClasses[index2] );
}
```

I've done a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FVVXx/11/ that works for this example, but this code is inside a function triggered on a certain time interval (it's a slider) and it does not work as in this example here.

In my code, the result for the first div is always `<div class="somediv class11 undefined">` where undefined should be`AllSecondCssClasses[index2]` -> class21

Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: You have some code error. instead of "some-div" in JS you should write "somediv". you should make sure the selectors are wrapped with apostrophe.

Comment: Your code is wrong I will post a correct one in jsfiddle. Look at what you're writing `$('div.some-div').eq(index)` - this is incorrect. can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please check again I've done some edits. (do a refresh )

Comment: You cannot invoke "addClass" directly on DOM element. you should wrap it with $().. when you write `$('div.somediv').eq(index)` you get a dom element. You want to do the following `$($('div.somediv').eq(index)).addClass...` notice the additional $()

Comment: Your question is incorrect still.. you're looking for `div-function1` in an array with the following values `['class11','class12','class13']` - so you get index -1, and then you get the item in that index from another array, so you get undefined.

Comment: My code is much more complex, please allow me to examine all variables. I will make proper edits in a sec.

Comment: ok I edited, please check again.

Comment: You write `addClass(firstClass + ' ' + secondClass )` , you should invoke "addClass" twice. Reading the code you will get `class11` on all divs. is this intentional?

Comment: you still need to wrap "eq" with $() -- I think this will also solve your problem. does "inArray" still doesn't work for you? because I get index2 == 0..

Comment: your code is the equivalent to `$("div.somediv").addClass("class11").addClass("class21")`.. your purpose it still unclear.

Comment: This is your current code with $() wrapping. all divs get class11 and class21 according to your algorithm. http://jsfiddle.net/FVVXx/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should write the algorithm with JQuery. If you can explain what you are trying to do, I will be able to help more.

```
$(function(){
var AllFirstCssClasses = [ 'class11', 'class12', 'class13' ];
var AllSecondCssClasses = [ 'class21', 'class22', 'class23' ];

function getParallelClass( firstClass ){
    return  AllSecondCssClasses[$.inArray(firstClass, AllFirstCssClasses)];
}

$("div.somediv").each(function(index,item){
      var $myDummy = $(this).attr("data-dummy");
      $(this).addClass($myDummy).addClass(getParallelClass( $myDummy) );
});

});
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FVVXx/14/)

Comment: I love your function, thanks so much, I guess my code only needed a little "bubble" to get the first div properly. THANKS a million, you scored :)